# Parsing a return string in Java

Tags: java

I am new to Java. Can someone please give me some clues on how to get the values from a string when the string returned is of this type:

```
[(key1,value1), (key2,value2), (key3, value3)]
```

Also note that value field may also contain a `,` comma.  I was not able to use GSON approach as the values are inside parenthesis and inside angular brackets. Is the only solution is to process the string first to replace all these to conform to the JSON structure?

Comment: TO put the question with more clarity, how can I retrieve the value1, value2 from a string                                                               [(key1,value1), (key2,value2), (key3, value3)]

Comment: Can you please write your question a bit more clear? And give us example of code?

Comment: Sorry, the question is how to retrieve the values from the above key-value pairs when they are inside a square brackets

Comment: all of this is one string? like this? `"[(key1,value1), (key2,value2), (key3, value3)]"` ?

Comment: Simple solution could be getting each elements between `(` and `)` and split them only on first `,`. `indexOf` and `substring` could be useful here. You could also use regex like `\(([^,]+),([^)]+)\)` - group 1 would contain key, group 2 value.

Comment: The ideal thing to do would be to change whatever code is generating this icky format to output something more standard instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a pretty simple example using a regular expression to search for the keys, and values. Note; this won't support key/value pairs that contain spaces. It assumes it's a single word.

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Iterator;


public class Main {
    private static final Pattern KEY_VALUE_PAIR = Pattern.compile("\\(\\s?+([^,\\s]+)\\s?,\\s?+([^)\\s?]+\\s?+)\\)");
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> pairs = getKeyValuePairs("[(key1,value1), (key2,value2), (key3, value3)]");
        Iterator it = pairs.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
            System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
            it.remove(); 
        }
    }

    private static Map<String, String> getKeyValuePairs(String input) {
        Map<String, String> matches = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Matcher m = KEY_VALUE_PAIR.matcher(input);
        while (m.find()) {
            matches.put(m.group(1), m.group(2));
        }
        return matches;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers. When I replaced the string with my problem string, I get the exact values I wanted. Really appreciate your time.  I was doing a legthy processing to parse the string and get the values.

Comment: String meta_data = file.getMetaTags().get("org.restlet.http.headers").toString();
            String str3 = meta_data.replace("[", "");
            String str4 = str3.replace("(","");
            String str5 = str4.replace(")","");
            String str6 = str5.replace("]", "");
            Set mySet = new HashSet();
            Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(str6.split(", ")));

Comment: Iterator iterator = set.iterator();
              while (iterator.hasNext()) {
              String str = (String)iterator.next();
               System.out.println("Iterator loop: " + iterator.next());
                    if (str.contains(",")){
                    String[] new_str = str.split(",");
                    map.put(new_str[0],new_str[1]);
                    }

Comment: Your program using Regex solved the problem.  I will explore more to learn pattern matching for similar problems. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few problems with your problem. As the parsed values and keys may contain a comma, and keys and values are only separated by comma, you can only guess if a number between to commas belong to the value or the key. Furthermore, you did not specify the types of key and value.

The following code does not throw exceptions if the input String is not formatted correctly and may run forever if you provide wrong input. Also, it interprets the **first comma as separator** between key and value.
I assume the **keys are and values are both of type String**, which can be parsed by yourself:

```
HashMap<String, String> result = new HashMap<>(6);
String text = "[(age,120), (eyes,5), (feet, 8)]";

int index = text.indexOf("[") + 1; // now one index after '['
while (index < text.length() && text.charAt(index) != '(')
    index++; //skip until we hit the start: '('


//this loop runs once for every pair (key, value). In this example three times
main: while(index < text.length()) {
    index++; //skip '('

    // parse the key, until a comma appears
    int keyStart = index;
    while (text.charAt(index) != ',') index++;
    int keyEnd = index;

    index++; //skip ','

    // parse the value, until a closing bracket appears
    int valueStart = index;
    while (text.charAt(index) != ')') index++;
    int valueEnd = index;

    // extract the actual Strings, using the parsed indices start & end
    String key = text.substring(keyStart, keyEnd).trim();
    String value = text.substring(valueStart, valueEnd).trim();
    result.put(key, value);

    // parse to the next pair (x,y), or exit
    while (text.charAt(index) != '(') {
        if(text.charAt(index) == ']')
            break main; // finish parsing, break main loop
        index++;
    }
}

System.out.println(result); // output = {feet=8, eyes=5, age=120}
```

*Irrelevant Notes*: This code runs efficiently. Code which uses String.substring, String.indexOf, or even Regular Expressions, Patterns, or similar, may process the same character multiple times.
In this code, every character is parsed exaclty once, and every relevant character (values and keys) is copied only once (and trimmed).

Furthermore, the syntax is relatively free: All irrelevant symbols like any text between two pairs, or **whitespace, is ignored**.
The syntax is as follows:

1. Any number (including 0) of Pairs between `[` and `]` will be parsed
2. Every Pair must be enclosed by brackets; key and value must be separated by comma. The first comma will be used. Example: `( name , value )`

A Name in a pair can contain any symbol, including `)` and `]`, except commas. A Value in a pair can contain every symbol, including `]` and `(`, except the closing bracket.
Whitespace around name and value will be removed. Example: `( my name , val,ue )` -> name = `my name` and value = `val,ue`. See String.trim().

`[(,)]` is also valid syntax and will result in empty Strings in the HashMap.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that I have not actually attempted to run this =)

The approach is basically to split the input about the regex "("  ")" to get an array of strings that represent pairs.

Then, you will iterate over this array, and extract everything that comes after the first ",". Here, we make the implicit assumption that keys may not contain the character ",".

```
String str[] = "[(key1,value1), (key2,value2), (key3, value3)]".split("(.*)");
ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<>();

String tmp;
for(int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  values.add(str[i].substring(str[i].indexOf(","), str[i].length()))
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this split on the text he wants and just leave the square brackets and separating commas?